# pushing a list to a file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a list like this

```
dis=('a','b','c',100)
```

I want it  to push to a `.Csv file(plan_to_prod2)` ,but my folder name is a integer

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(dis)
my_df.to_csv('E:\23\4\plan_to_prod2.csv')
```

i am getting invalid  file name as error even though my file name is correct

Comment: Could you please share the exact text of the error along with the full stacktrace?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'E:\x13\x04\plan_to_prod2.csv'

Comment: @maniramreddy : you better edit (add extra info) the question than comment(s).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a raw string literal.

A `\` followed by an integer is interpreted as a unicode character which is an invalid file name. Try `print('E:\23\4\plan_to_prod2.csv')` and see the output (I would have pasted it here but these characters don't show up when the answer is rendered). You can also see the problem in the error you provided in the comment.

When using raw string:

```
 print(r'E:\23\4\plan_to_prod2.csv')
 # E:\23\4\plan_to_prod2.csv
```

Instead of using raw string you can also use double slashes, ie `print('E:\\23\\4\\plan_to_prod2.csv')` but I find using raw strings much easier.

Comment: @maniramreddy You should *edit* you question with  the current state of your code and the current error + full stacktrace you are getting.

Comment: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\23\\4\\plan_to_prod2.csv'

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character is used for escapes. So when you try to find the path you escape.

You should use `/` or use raw string r'' instead of `\`. Also, you could escape those backslashes by escaping it with an additional `\`.Choose whichever suits you best.

```
r'E:\23\4\plan_to_prod2.csv'
'E:\\23\\4\\plan_to_prod2.csv'
'E:/23/4/plan_to_prod2.csv'
```